# Error: Check that native modules use compatible support package versions for installed Expo SDK

Tags: react-native

Detailed check results:

> Expected package `@expo/config-plugins@~7.2.2` Found invalid:
>  `@expo/config-plugins@4.1.5`   (for more info, run: npm why
> @expo/config-plugins) Advice: Upgrade dependencies that are using the
> invalid package versions.

One or more checks failed, indicating possible issues with the project.

React native

When I tried to upload my project to expo dev, expo doctor gave me this error, but it was changed to `@expo/config-plugins@~7.2.2` version